# How to fix "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve *" error

Tags: webpack

I am using very basic webpack configuration with 3rd party modules being used in my server.js. While compiling with webpack, i am getting tons of error all saying that module can not be found. I have searched a lots of similar questions and answers, but i could not find any correct one or any answer actually answering this question...

Some say that i have to include all the missing modules into dependencies, but it's like *a lots of these errors*, should i really include them all? Some answer was that i can ignore them, but it did not work out for me. Used it like so: [Webpack build fails #295](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/issues/295#issuecomment-368311241)

**Folder structure for server**

[image]

**Webpack config**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: "./server.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "server.bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**Error log**

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vash' in '/Users/X/server/node_modules/consolidate/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js 1553:51-66
 @ ./node_modules/consolidate/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/email-templates/lib/index.js
 @ ./common/Helpers.js
 @ ./server.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'velocityjs' in '/Users/X/server/node_modules/consolidate/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js 201:63-84
 @ ./node_modules/consolidate/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/email-templates/lib/index.js
 @ ./common/Helpers.js
 @ ./server.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'walrus' in '/Users/X/server/node_modules/consolidate/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js 1023:55-72
 @ ./node_modules/consolidate/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/email-templates/lib/index.js
 @ ./common/Helpers.js
 @ ./server.js
```

Comment: Had the same issue. I solved it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64895428/10944219

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I would `yarn` to have it resolve as many of those as it can automatically, and then `yarn add` all of the packages it still complains about. So `yarn add vash` etc.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem, it stemmed from Visual Studio Code. I was writing "const" but it took that as autocomplete or something as "cons" so it added "import cons from "consolidate";" to the top of my file. I finally figured it out by deleting the consolidate folder from node_modules, it then pointed to which component file was showing "import cons from "consolidate";" at the top.

So delete consolidate folder from node_modules, find what file is asking for "import cons from "consolidate";", delete that line. And if you're so inclined do NPM install again.

Edit: or use a linter, that should figure it out faster than deleting the file

Answer (score -3):

The solution for this was wrong project structure, where I had node_modules as in a child folder, but the parent folder had node_modules as well. At least it was not webp[ack's fault for sure. Probably you are doing something wrong. Good luck!